# ATA IDE IDENTIFY

Tags: c, operating-system, systems-programming, ata

I am trying to develop ide ata driver for my os learning .. i am facing a problem that after sending IDENTIFY CMD the system hang up with no panic ..!
i am using the below code

```
/* ATA specs say these values must be zero before sending IDENTIFY */
outportb(io + ATA_REG_SECCOUNT0, 0);
outportb(io + ATA_REG_LBA0, 0);
outportb(io + ATA_REG_LBA1, 0);
outportb(io + ATA_REG_LBA2, 0);
/* Now, send IDENTIFY */
Printf("Sending IDENTIFY to port 0x%X\n",io);
outportb(io + ATA_REG_COMMAND, ATA_CMD_IDENTIFY);
Printf("Sent IDENTIFY\n");
/* Now, read status port */
uint8_t status = inportb(io + ATA_REG_STATUS);
Printf("\nThe status right now is %d", status);
if (status)
{
    Printf("\nNow Polling... _IRQP = %d , _IRQS= %d",_IRQP,_IRQS);
    /* Now, poll untill BSY is clear. */
    //while (inportb(io + ATA_REG_STATUS) & ATA_SR_BSY != 0);
    while (!_IRQP || !_IRQS){}
    Printf("\nFinished Polling... _IRQP = %d , _IRQS= %d", _IRQP, _IRQS);
```

it never reach "Sent Identify" .. and some thime it writes Sen and hang.

i have tested on Virtualbox and VMWare as well and the same result.
any idea why it is hanging up?

Comment: Have you checked if any exceptions are raised? You're on x86, right?

Comment: yep, ia m in x86 protected mode , and yes if exception is raised my panic will catch.